# Wordpress website - Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage error

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer

Here is Link for my website http://dentalgroupofmillburn.com/
(Works fine on Chrome and FF)
i am using IE-8 to open the website. Sometime all of the pages Open propely and sometimes Shows the following error

[image]

if I tried few times on an error page then it works again.

The Question is whether the problem is with IE or the Wordpress site or the host and whats the 
Solutin in that case.
Tried few things available on forums but not got right.

Comment: if your website is running properly than problem must be in your browser. try clearing your cache and cookies and try again

Comment: IE10 reports troubles with a security certificate, and loads the page only partially.

Comment: Watch the loading of the site with Fiddler. It will provide more meaningful errors.

Comment: @ericLaw fiddler Shows there is certain delay in response time from server. then how could i manage this???

Comment: "Delay" couldn't cause this (unless it's >5minutes). What are the HTTP response codes? Do you see any HTTPS Certificate error popups?

Comment: @ericLaw the HTTP response codes are 301->200 and i did'nt see any certificate error popups. Also suggest that why there is delay in opening the site. i.e loading time